# Start next landscape long table on the same page as where previous landscape long table midway ended

Tags: tables, longtable, landscape, pdflscape, clearpage

In the appendix of my thesis I have multiple consecutive landscape long tables. Quite a lot of them they end midway of the page. I would like to start the following table on the same page, instead of a new page what is happening now. Below is a MWE

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{book}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\title{A longtable example}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
    \caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long} \\

    \toprule \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \midrule 
    \endfirsthead
    
    \multicolumn{3}{c}%
    {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \midrule \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \midrule 
    \endhead
    
    \midrule \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \midrule
    \endfoot
    
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    
    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}


\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
\caption{A sample long table.} \label{tab:long2} \\

\toprule \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \midrule 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{3}{c}%
{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
\midrule \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{First column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Second column}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Third column}} \\ \midrule 
\endhead

\midrule \multicolumn{3}{r}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \midrule
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

    One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\ One & abcdef ghjijklmn & 123.456778 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you end the landscape environment in the middle if you don't want it to end?

Comment: just delete `\end{landscape}
\begin{landscape}`

Comment: It just didn't cross my mind, been looking at it for hours :') Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

both `\begin{landscape}` and `\end{landscape}` call `\clearpage` so you always get a page break, however you can put both `longtable` in the same `landscape` ie delete the middle

```
\end{landscape} 
\begin{landscape}
```